# Ajax request is ok but receiving data in error response text

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax and today facing a weird problem.I am receiving response data in error block instead of success block.And more strange is that data is inside xhr.responseText.And its working fine also.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: th_elem_ajax_obj.ajaxurl,
    dataType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        'action': 'pull_course_paged',
        'offset' : offset,
        'settings' : settings
    },
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        jQuery('.ajax-replace').html(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        // console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

I cant realize this error why its in error block

Comment: Check the Network Console. Which HTTP Code you are receiving ?

Comment: @HarishST status 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

This might not fix the problem, but there are few things you could or should change:

- add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`
- change dataType to `"json"`. This is what you expect *back*.

```
    // i think stringifying is optional but wouldn't hurt.
    data: JSON.stringify({'action': 'pull_course_paged', 'offset' : offset, 'settings' : settings}),
```

hth.